# Converting Time into a Double Swift

Tags: swift, int, nsdate

I am new to Swift, and am stuck on a little problem.
I have the current hour and minute(s) as Ints, and would like to know how to put them together, to create one whole number, like military times.
WITHOUT CONVERTING TO STRING, as I need to be able to compare ( using < and >) later on.

EXAMPLE:

- Current Hour 02
- Current Minute  24
- I would like 0224

Comment: This is pretty simple math. "hours * 100 + minutes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the current hour by 100 then add the number of minutes. From your example:

```
02 * 100 = 200
200 + 24 = 224
```

Comment: Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example

```
var num:Int = 02
print(num)
var num2:Int = 24

Double.init("\(num)\(num2)")
```